# Ошбки в html validator

Tags: css, wordpress, html5, валидация, pagespeed-insights

Сайт WordPress, проверяю в PageSpeed Insights и validator.w3.org. Может кто-то подсказать по поводу первого и второго. Как можно поднять и исправить. По скоросте я ужимал фото и  код некоторых файлоы *.css,*.js. Что можно сделать ещё с ним, для ттого что бы получить выше оценку. 
По валидатору было порядка 20 ошибок, из зафиксил. Осталось 3 ошибки, но когда я начал просматривать, то понял следующую штуку.Мой сайт вот http://intellect-media.biz

> Валидатор тот с каким-то багом, или я не знаю как он проверяет... 1
>   ошибка  Есть в коде  тег открывающий и закрывающий , как оно
>   проверяется в ручную, вводится в источнике кода поиск

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ на вопрос про pagespeed: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743821/220220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **О скорости загрузки вашего веб-сайта**. Ваш веб-сайт имеет **[скорость первоначальной загрузки (без кеша) более 8 секунд](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/170716_4K_6H1/)**. Статистика сообщает, что пользователи с мобильными устройствами ожидают загрузки между 2 и 3-мя секундами. Так как в настоящее время эти пользователи составляют немного более 50% трафика в сети, то ваш-вебсайт имеет те же самые - более 50% - потеря трафика. Для подробного анализа скорости загрузки, откройте предложенную ссылку тестера скорости и щелкните на Waterfall. Там есть два Waterfall - первоначальной загрузки и после кеширования. С этими окнами вы можете анализировать и оптимизировать ваши файлы и изображения. Например: изображение *[**этой картинки**](http://intellect-media.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/6d0d395f36c2e70cbd78360800ba869f.png)* - тестер сообщает, что закачанный объём картинки составляет 4,5 KB, а несжатый объём = 4,3 KB (Uncompressed Size: 4.3 KB)

[image: Анализатор скорости загрузки веб-страниц]

Вы можете изменить размер картинки, на размер реального показа, также можете изменять формат картинки, например на jpeg (jpg), с **[этим инструментом](https://pixlr.com/editor/)**. Вы можете сжимать размер картинки с **[этим инструментом](https://tinyjpg.com/)**. Обратите внимание, что простой перевод картинки в формат jpeg (jpg), сэкономит, примерно 50% объёма картинки. **[Статья Гугл о оптимизации изображений и о технике Art direction + о атрибуте srcset](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/images?hl=ru)**. В настоящее время для ускорения загрузки мобильных веб-сайтов Гугл создал **[AMP - Accelerated Mobile Pages](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/)**. Здесь создана специальная cdn, которая и выполняет всю работу. Вы можете выбирать **[шаблон для вашего веб-сайта](https://ampbyexample.com/)** и проверять ваши веб-страницы на **[валидаторе](https://validator.ampproject.org/)**.

- **О ошибках исходного кода**. **[Валидатор указывает конкретные ошибки](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&acceptlanguage=&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fintellect-media.biz%2F)** вашего исходного кода. Например: Section lacks heading - Секция не имеет заголовка. Семантические элементы Main, section, article требуют заголовков с атрибутами h - **[статья W3](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)**. Заголовки помогают браузеру понимать структуру страницы. Из заголовков, поисковики получают информацию Длинного Хвоста. Проверьте **структуру главной страницы вашего сайта**. Вы можете видеть, что первый заголовок - Остались вопросы? - даёт мало информации о веб-странице. 
  Следующая ошибка исходного кода: End tag article seen, but there were open elements - есть закрытый элемент article, но нет открытого этого элемента. 
  Unclosed element div - незакрытый элемент div. Вы можете самостоятельно находить эти элементы в исходном коде и исправлять их. Ошибки исходного кода также понижают скорость загрузки веб-страниц, так как браузер тратит лишнее время на построение **[объектной модели документа DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)**. Ещё раз рекомендую вам применять AMP - Accelerated Mobile Pages для вашего веб-сайта - [статьи об этом](http://searchengineland.com/library/google/google-amp-project). Пример скорости загрузки страницы AMP = **[87/100 для мобильных](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsweden-tourist.com%2Fsights%2Fen%2Fkalmar-en.html)**.