# Google ругается сам на себя в Google PageSpeed Insights по поводу шрифтов

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, seo, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет!)
Стоит задача - выйти хотя бы на уровень 85-90 по Google PageSpeed Insights. Но вот незадача.. все что делаю по рекомендациям в его списке, он не воспринимает или всеравно выдает одно и тоже.

И кэши обновляла(кэш сервера сайта, кэш базы данных, кэши всех браузеров и даже винду от мусора чистила и комп перезагружала). Он воспринял только то что я оптимизировала указывающие им картинки и обратно залила уже оптимизированные.

И только 2 картинки оставил в списке требований вместо 12 как было ранее. Но. Остальное-то оставил гадина.

И вот мучаюсь 4-й день как бы мне поднять показатели в мобильно версии с 58 до 85...

[Отчёт по сайту здесь.](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https://www.buskuz.com/)

Вот скрин: шрифты которые подключаются через Google Fonts.

[image: шрифты которые подключаются через GoogleFonts]

Вот скрин по JavaScript который подключается от API Google:

[image: JavaScript который подключается от APi Goole]

Вот скрин `.htaccess`

[image: htaccess-файл]

Помогите плиз, а то мои мозги уже плавятся.. я перепробовала все что нашла в инете. и плагины для сео и сжатия подкрутила, и кеши чищу, и Бд оптимизировала.

Comment: Обратите внимание на ошибки исходного кода вашей стартовой веб-страницы https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.buskuz.com%2F . Для подробного анализа скорости загрузки используйте этот инструмент http://www.webpagetest.org/ - щелкайте на Waterfall и на проблемные бары.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оптимизация сайта на Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743821/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Гугл ругается на следующие вещи:

1. Один из тегов `<script>` с файлом у вас в начале кода страницы. По рекомендациям гугла [все скрипты нужно перенести в самый конец](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).
2. [По CCS со шрифтами аналогичные рекомендации](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery). Гугл будет доволен если вы их вообще удалите, или если будете загружать асинхронно. Второе означает что гости сайта рискуют увидеть часть сайта без шрифтов.
3. Дальше гугл ругается на долгую загрузку страницы. Эту проблему относительно легко исправить: для вордпресса есть куча кеширующих модулей.

С кешем ресурсов самого гугла ничего нельзя сделать, кроме как вообще отказаться от их использования. Последнее обычно не вариант.

Оптимизация картинок тоже задача решаемая. Другой вопрос что это не всегда стоит делать: если пережимать все картинки под требования гугла, то они могут покрыться неприятными артефактами. Может стоить оставить картинки в покое.

Кроме того, можно поработать над разгрузкой главной страницы. Сейчас она весит, страшно сказать, *два с лишним мегабайта только HTML*, без картинок. Это никуда не годится. Только представьте, сколько такая страница будет открываться с телефона по 3G.

Comment: 1. Совет годится только если на сайте есть преоладер, который будет крутиться, пока сайт грузится.
2. Шрифты лучше подключать самому, без отсылки к гуглу.
3. В WP столько всего понамешано, что объединить файлы стилей и скриптов не представляется возможным.
4. Для WP и иже с ним показатель в 70-80 это норма.

Это так, дополнения))

Comment: @DaemonHK все можно, и объединенить (есть лёгкий плагин для этого), и получить выше 90. Я добивался 92 на сайте с тяжёлой "красивой" темой.

Comment: @DaemonHK почитайте мой ответ на аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743821/220220

Comment: @KAGGDesign читал же)) даже плюс поставил. Тяжелая "красивая" тема это лендинг? Сколько сторонних плагинов использовалось?

Comment: @DaemonHK да я увидел, что читали, а чего ж тогда такой комментарий пишете?) Тема - нет, не лендинг, с themeforest, со всякими украшательствами. 35 плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

1) Касательно шрифтов. Гугл ругается не столько на шрифты, как на css который вы подгружаете удаленно.

Решение, которое использую я:
Переходим по линке, которая используется для подключения шрифтов в теге.
Мы увидим содержимое CSS который собственно подключает шрифты. Копируем в локальный файл CSS и подключаем его вместо запроса на гугл. Ошибка уйдет.

2) Удаленные гугловские скрипты - это больно, но решаемо.
Решение, которое использую я:
Как вариант - зарузить эти срипты в локальные файлы и подключить локальные. Далее по крону периодически загружать актуальные версии этих скриптов. Метод проверенный.

Успехов!