# После отключения Cloudflare сайт пингуется, но недоступен

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

Добрый день! Связался на фрилансе с задачей. Оптимизация индийского сайта https://gettodeal.com. Сайт на Wordpress + WooCommerce + куча "нужных плагинов которые нельзя удалять".

С внутренней стороной (база данных итд) более-менее понятно, там просто чистка товаров которые не нужны и оптимизация БД. Далее стоит задача сократить размер страницы отдаваемой в браузер с 1.2 Мб до 500 Кб, уменьшить время загрузки до 2 секунд.

Я заметил что примерно 300 Килобайт + лишние 4-5 сек - это скрипты от Cloudflare через которую идут обращения на сайт. Клиент говорит, что CloudFlare ему не нужен, можно выключить. Однако после его отключения браузеры выдают ошибку ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, хотя сайт прекрасно пингуется по истинному IP сервера (а до выключения команда ping на домен показывает IP серверов Cloudflare).

В чем может быть дело?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А как вы отключаете Cloudflare?

Comment: Отключать cloud - неправильная тема вообще. О каких скриптах речь? Там вижу только rocket. Этот режим можно и убрать в консоли Cloudflare.

Comment: А, вообще, вы зря взялись за такую задачу с кривым клиентом. Ну раз уж взялись, почитайте вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743821/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/743906#743906

Comment: Отключает cloud сам клиент, а как отключает - не объясняет почему-то)))

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо за ссыль по оптимизации, отличный текст.

Comment: @KAGGDesign: гм, вчера еще скрипт был от CFL, видимо после отключений-включений что-то изменилось и только rocket остался. Уже лучше. Вчера rocket грузился 4 сек, сегодня 0.8 сек только.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75842/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-ndanilov2015).

Comment: @KAGGDesign, увы и ах, уже не поможет ничего. Клиенту начало мерещится что вёрстка съехала и фотографии искривились из-за моих работ с базой, хотя я помню что так было изначально, но в итоге он потребовал откатить всё назад и начать работу заново.

Я ему написал "I will not do this job again. let's close the contract and you'll hire yourself another specialist. Or I can try recovery functional of site with this database which was optimized." - и он разорвал контракт, щас JSS упадёт в ноль на UpWORK раз это первый заказ там был...

Comment: Ну и ладно. Напишите сами на него жалобу в администрацию UpWork ))

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что при подключении Cloudflare к сайту на WordPress, со стороны Cloudflare нужно перенаправлять DNS домена на сервера DNS Cloudflare. Потому и сайт доступен по "...истинному IP сервера...".

Все что нужно сделать, это зайти в панель управления доменом и установить правильные NS сервера(изменить из DNS Cloudflare на свои, которые ведут на сервер, где развернут сайт).

Примечения, чтобы изменения вступили в силу, могут пройти от 1-го до 72-х часов, поэтому, сначала изменяем DNS домена, потом отключаем подключение сайта к Cloudflare (когда изменения вступят в силу).

Comment: Я думаю, он всё это понимает ("а до выключения команда ping на домен показывает IP серверов Cloudflare")

Comment: Кроме того, чтобы отключить кеширование cloud, достаточно нажать на значок облака в DNS секции админки Cloudflare, чтобы облако стало серым. Все.

Comment: @KAGGDesign: ping после того, как клиент выключит Cloud, сразу идёт на нужный сервер. DNS сразу обновляются.