# Оптимизация любой темы WordPress

Tags: wordpress, оптимизация, seo, оптимизация-сайтов

Какими плагинами, да и вообще, какими любыми методами можно облегчить загрузку темы вордпресс.
Была выбрана авторская тема от Automattic, но она на удивление имеет проблемы-таки. Все из-за того, что в нее внедрили использование плагина дополнительного, чтобы сама тема отображалась внешне и работала более корректно.

Конечно, проще найти другую тему готовую уже под СЕО.

Но все же.

Тема понравилась, довольно удобна собой и видом и функциями для микроблоггинга. Как оптимизировать по максимуму такой сайт с плагинами?

Сама тема с выключенным доп-ым плагином меньше влияет на сео. но без него это не шаблон уже.

Comment: Стандартных решений нет. Есть лишь некие общие моменты, пути оптимизации, а конкретное их воплощение зависит от темы. Почитайте мой ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743906/220220

Comment: да читал. установил и все равно красные флажки выдает гугл. впрочем как и другие тесторы тоже не утешают результатом. и кстати что с кешем что без гугл одинаковый выдает результат.

Comment: Установил - что? Для оптимизации основной темы надо кодить в дочерней. И в каждой теме по-своему.

Comment: основные указанные плагины из топика - PageSpeed,  WP Super Cache. еще пробовал на сайте PageSpeed Ninja, Optimize, Clearfy

Comment: В упомянутом ответе речь идёт о **модуле** PageSpeed. Это серверное программное обеспечение, составная часть Apache или nginx. Но и PageSpeed модуль не решит всех проблем. Без анализа кода темы, и кодирования в дочерней теме вопрос не решить. Никакая комбинация установленных плагинов/модуля не поможет в общем случае.

Answer (score 1):

> какими любыми методами можно облегчить загрузку темы вордпрес

Загружается не "тема", а сайт. 
Техническая оптимизация сайта - это комплексный и индивидуальный подход.

Для вешнего анализа стоит пользоваться нормальными сервисами: https://tools.pingdom.com/, https://gtmetrix.com/, http://www.webpagetest.org/ и тп. Но только не [гуглофейком](http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=945499) (PageSpeed Insights), который даёт липовые, в большинстве своём ненужные "рекомендации" и не даёт действительно нужной инфы.

Для внутреннего же анализа стоит использовать плагины-анализаторы. Я, лично, первым делом устанавливаю https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

В целом же по оптимизации ВП (и не только для ВП) рекомендую посмотреть доклады одного из разработчика ВП:
http://wordpress.tv/2016/10/08/konstantin-kovshenin-memory-devourers-in-wordpress/
http://wordpress.tv/2015/08/20/konstantin-kovshenin-wordpress-performance-killers/
http://wordpress.tv/2014/09/02/konstantin-kovshenin-scaling-wordpress/
(Это то, что по-русски, а так на английском на wordpress.tv есть намного больше)

Comment: если учесть query-monitor данные то вообще отлично все, хотя остальные тесторы указывают на совсем иную ситуацию. так кто же прав? кому верить

Comment: Мне не ведомо про какие "остальные тесторы" ты говоришь. QM показывает измерения не просто на сервере, а с учётом нагрузок при вызове ***конкретной*** странице. Его смотреть нужно не в админке, а на фронте.

Comment: остальные которые остались не сказанными и взятыми из твоего ответа какими пользоваться. на фронте и нормально выглядит все. критичных данных нет

Comment: ,,,,,,,,,,,,........,,,,,,,,,,, - дарю тебе  эти знаки препинания - пользуйся, что бы было возможно разобрать твой поток сознания.