# От чего зависит время ответа сервера?

Tags: wordpress, веб-сервер

От чего зависит время ответа сервера?

Если сайт на движке WordPress находится на виртуальном хостинге, то время ответа сервера 1.1с это нормально или нет?

Замеряю время ответа сервра в Google PageSpeed - показывает 1.1с. Это как я понимаю время загрузки контента?

А замеряю TTFB с помощью Netpeak Spider - показывает 198мс.

В общем для [этого](https://stroy-dok.com/) сайта нормальное время ответа сервера или нет?

Оставить все как есть или нужно еще оптимизировать?

Comment: Вот это косяки https://yadi.sk/i/IhPZV72e0mUWcA

Comment: А как вы их смотрите? В отладчике браузера? Пытаюсь посмотреть, захожу во вкладку NetWork, ошибок нет для главной страницы. Как воспроизвести эти косяки?

Comment: Да, смотрел в отладке барузера, видимо сервер крыло, ибо в данный момент с сервера подгружаются эти файлы...

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed показывает общее время загрузки страницы (1.1 с). А TTFB - это время до первого байта от сервера (198 мс).

PageSpeed начинает ругаться, когда TTFB больше 200 мс. У вас на пределе.

Ну и 1 с - это уже на "прогретом" сайте. Первое посещение - 5 секунд. Потому что кеши на сервере устарели. При большом потоке новый пользователь будет получать страницу за 1 секунду.

В целом нормально.

Более подробно о подходах к оптимизации сайта на WP можно почитать здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743906/220220