# Как устранить все недостатки сайта на Wordpress в новом Google PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

Для моего сайта результат для мобильных - 1/100, для ПК - 27/100. Ссылка на [тест](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisrael-escorts.com%2F&tab=desktop).

Как устранить все недостатки [сайта](https://israel-escorts.com) на Wordpress в новом Google PageSpeed Insights?

Возможно, что кто-то уже решал подобные задачи для сайтов на WP, поделитесь, пожалуйста, ссылками на статьи или решением, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я писал об этом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743906/220220 Кое-что устарело, но в целом можно принять как начальное рукодство к действию.

Comment: До вчера всё было ОК, а тут вдруг стало плохо потому, что какой-то фейковый недосервис так решил? https://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=1004306 
И да вопрос не по теме SO

Comment: @KAGGDesign модуля mod_pagespeed для Apache нет, попробую поставить сейчас

Comment: @SeVlad до нововведений в Google PageSpeed Insights сайт был в зеленой зоне и для мобильных и для ПК

Comment: Я в курсе (нытьё по всему интернету 3й день), а ты даже не думаешь. Почитай по ссылке  KAGG Desig-а и мой ответ. И топики на сёрче что я давал тут и там.

Answer (score 3):

Проверьте ваш веб-сайт с аудитом **[Lighthouse](https://web.dev/measure)**.

Проверьте критические ресурсы вашего веб-сайта с использованием инструмента **[WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)** (рекомендован Гугл).

Для оптимизации ваших критических ресурсов используйте руководство Гугл **[Оптимизация процесса визуализации](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/optimizing-critical-rendering-path)**.

Для оптимизации ваших изображений используйте рекомендации из **[Отзывчивые изображения Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)**. Здесь может быть полезным обратить внимание на тот факт, что назначать разные файлы изображений для разных медиа запросов или форматов изображений с использованием элемента **[picture](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)**. Например:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="head.jpg, head-2x.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="head-small.jpg, head-small-2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="head-fb.jpg" srcset="head-fb-2x.jpg 2x" alt="a head carved out of wood">
</picture>
```

Также вы можете использовать следующий код, который  позволит браузеру автоматически вычислить оптимальную плотность пикселей и выбрать корректное изображение для загрузки используя элемент **[srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)**:

```html
<img src="lighthouse-200.jpg" srcset="lighthouse-100.jpg 100w, lighthouse-200.jpg 200w,lighthouse-400.jpg 400w, lighthouse-800.jpg 800w, lighthouse-1000.jpg 1000w, lighthouse-1400.jpg 1400w, lighthouse-1800.jpg 1800w" alt="a lighthouse">
```

Обратите внимание что в настоящее время самые "легкие" изображения являются изображения имеющие формат JPG (JPEG). Для изменения формата изображений и для изменения величины изображений вы можете использовать инструмент **[Photo Editor PIXLR](https://pixlr.com/x/)**.

Для сжатия изображений может быть полезен инструмент **[ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/online)**.