# Глабальная смена формата изображений на сайте (не только picture, но и background)

Tags: javascript, php, изображения, joomla3

В попытках повысить цифры по Google speed , следовал его рекомендациям и поменял все изображения на сайте на формат webp.  Разумеется без задней мысли о кроссбраузерности. Теперь Mozilla, Safari и IE не могут отобразить изображения. Фотографии были загружены и выводились как через таблицу стилей, так и через админ часть (Joomla ).

Возможно кто-то может помочь в реализации следующей функции. Определить браузер с которого зашел посетитель (знаю что не безопасный вариант, но другого ничего не призодит) и глобально менять все изображения на сайте с формата webp на png. Все дубли изображений будут заранее лежать в тех же директориях.

Возможно идея бредовая,  но как это можно реализовать еще ?

UPD Библиотека Picturefill.js не пойдет, так как она не затрагивает изображения вставляемые через свойство css background.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev нет, эта библиотека не касается изображений вставляемых через css

Comment: Для css используем Modernizr  и потом в css можно делать так

Comment: .no-webp .logo { background-image: url(logo.png); }
.webp .logo { background-image: url(logo.webp); }

Comment: НО браузер будет грузить обе картинки, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev знаю об этом варианте, но он действительно не хороший. 
Я пробую найти media запросы для разных браузеров. Нашел для Mozilla, но для IE не могу найти такого решения. Так же Safari нужен.

Comment: И этот вариант не хороший, он  не будет учитывать версию браузера. Вообще я бы на вашем месте пока с этим не заморачивался....Гляньте поддержку https://caniuse.com/#search=webp, даже сравнительно свежие версии новый формат не поддерживают.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать общепринятый формат JPEG (jpg) с оптимизацией каждого вашего изображения как я рекомендовал в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940233/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-google-pagespeed-insight/940309#940309

Comment: Когда Гугл рекомендует использовать новые форматы, то, вероятно, это означает любые форматы, но оптимизированные.

Comment: @nikant25 но это не лишает нас замечания об использовании современных форматов.

Answer (score 0):

Пока я искал ответ Mozilla выпустила обновление и теперь этот браузер, как и Opera, Chrome поддерживает формат webp. Тем не менее, проблему с Safari, Edge решать не сильно спешат. Для себя решил вопрос обнаружения браузера Edge, Safari и вставкой кода в тег body. Далее для них идут отдельные стили.

Вот код обнаружения браузера (не самый лучший вариант, да и код частично лишь мой)

```js
    //safari css hack
    var isSafari = navigator.vendor && navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1 &&
                   navigator.userAgent &&
                   navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS') == -1 &&
                   navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FxiOS') == -1;
    if(isSafari == true){
      var saf = document.getElementById("site-body");
      saf.classList.add('img-of-future');
    }


  // Get IE or Edge browser version
  var version = detectIE();

 if (version >= 12) {
    console.log(document.innerHTML = 'Edge ' + version);
    var saf = document.getElementById("site-body");
    saf.classList.add('img-of-future');
  }

  /**
   * detect IE
   * returns version of IE or false, if browser is not Internet Explorer
   */
  function detectIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
      // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
      return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что человек может зайти на сайт со старой версии браузера?

Comment: Да, конечно.это далеко не идеальное решение, но для тех кому "очень надо" должно подойти, как это было со мной.